# Bootstrap Fixed size image gallery with caption

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I want is to create a fixed size image gallantry. Every image has a fixed width and height 80x80. And there will be one more line under each image, which will be the image ID. When the screen size changed. Number of images per row will be changed automatically.

Something like:

```
<div class="container">
    <span><p><img src="1.png" width="80"></p></span>
    <span><p><img src="2.png" width="80"></p></span>
    <span><p><img src="3.png" width="80"></p></span>
    <span><p><img src="4.png" width="80"></p></span>
    <span><p><img src="5.png" width="80"></p></span>
</div>
```

Expecting:

```
image1    image2    image3   image4
1.png     2.png     3.png     4.png

image5
5.png
```

My code is not working as p cannot be embedded in span. I think what's needed is a container that can be stacked horizontally, and it can hold elements in 2 lines. And I don't want to use the "col col-xxx" class since it will automatically change the image width. I want to width to be fixed. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your current code, this will make it easier for people to help you

Comment: Yes, there are display issues on my code. I've just finished editing. Thanks

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/aWKgjP

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Michael!